# gcsfuse: ls directory with 30,000+ files results in ls: reading directory [directory]: Input/output error

Tags: linux, gcloud, gcsfuse

I have a mounted gcsfuce bucket that after the ls command is given resports an Input/Output error.

Version:
`gcsfuse version 0.21.0 (Go version go1.8)`

Mount Command:

```
gcsfuse -o rw -o allow_other --implicit-dirs --foreground --debug_fuse --debug_gcs --limit-ops-per-sec -1 --debug_invariants --stat-cache-ttl 5m --type-cache-ttl 5m --file-mode 777
```

The bucket has been mounted sucessfully and the credentials are loaded using environment variables. This is on a local machine, not a cloud instance.

Here is the output from the `ls` command:

```
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
gcs: Req              0x0: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x0: -> ListObjects() (325.872438ms): OK
Mounting file system...
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000001        connection.go:395] <- init
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000001        connection.go:474] -> OK ()
File system has been successfully mounted.
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000002        connection.go:395] <- GetInodeAttributes (inode 1)
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000002        connection.go:474] -> OK ()
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000003        connection.go:395] <- unknown (inode 1, opcode 22)
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000003        connection.go:476] -> Error: "function not implemented"
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000004        connection.go:395] <- OpenDir (inode 1)
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000004        connection.go:474] -> OK ()
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000005        connection.go:395] <- ReadDir (inode 1)
gcs: Req              0x1: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x1: -> ListObjects() (180.571707ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x2: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x2: -> ListObjects() (175.277735ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x3: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x3: -> ListObjects() (170.263641ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x4: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x4: -> ListObjects() (243.624532ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x5: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x5: -> ListObjects() (181.245961ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x6: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x6: -> ListObjects() (140.484663ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x7: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x7: -> ListObjects() (198.758211ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x8: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x8: -> ListObjects() (168.88662ms): OK
gcs: Req              0x9: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0x9: -> ListObjects() (219.064727ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xa: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xa: -> ListObjects() (180.064346ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xb: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xb: -> ListObjects() (159.562584ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xc: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xc: -> ListObjects() (137.711911ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xd: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xd: -> ListObjects() (167.276919ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xe: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xe: -> ListObjects() (240.187708ms): OK
gcs: Req              0xf: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req              0xf: -> ListObjects() (191.353085ms): OK
gcs: Req             0x10: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req             0x10: -> ListObjects() (152.391675ms): OK
gcs: Req             0x11: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req             0x11: -> ListObjects() (175.962066ms): OK
gcs: Req             0x12: <- ListObjects()
gcs: Req             0x12: -> ListObjects() (105.252904ms): OK
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000005        connection.go:474] -> OK ()
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000006        connection.go:395] <- ReleaseDirHandle
fuse_debug: Op 0x00000006        connection.go:474] -> OK ()
```

Result:

```
ls: reading directory [directory]: Input/output error
total 0
```

Comment: Opcode 22 is [`OpGetxattr`](https://github.com/jacobsa/fuse/blob/8c94df5ce913877b3ba7f417aae0414bf78f7ddc/internal/fusekernel/fuse_kernel.go#L364). I guess your version of `ls` is looking for extended attributes and failing when the file system signals it doesn't support them. It seems like the file system isn't doing anything wrong here... What OS is this?

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It does however work on the subdirectories.

Comment: Please try building from source (or a 0.41 release) and you should be able to see some improvements.